# Get log entries written while executing command

Tags: bash

I have a service that writes to a file in /var/log. For testing purposes, I am looking for a way to extract just the log lines that are written while executing a command against the service. I know I could do it with a C program using fseek/ftell, but that would require extra tooling in the VM. I would prefer a pure bash solution (bash 4.4, Ubuntu 18.04). I thought maybe something about using tail -f might work, but I can't figure out exactly how to work that.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `diff` command. It takes 2 files as input and prints differing lines. You can copy the log file before execution of the service and compare it to the original file afterwords.

```sh
$ cat > logfile
line 1
line 2 asdf
```

```
$ cp logfile logfile-old
$ cat >> logfile
Third one.
Oups. Error occured.
```

```
$ diff logfile logfile-old
3,4d2
< Third one.
< Oups. Error occured.
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, especially when combined with the -n flag (for RCS format) and then piping through tail -n +2 (to skip the first line).